# How to get CPU utilisation, RAM utilisation in MAC from commandline

Tags: macos

I know that using Activity Monitor we can see CPU utilisation.But i want to get this information of my remote system through script. top command is not helpful for me. Please comment me any other way to get it.

Comment: Please let me know the mistake. So that i can improve my question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What is the objection to `top` in logging mode?

```
top -l 1 | grep -E "^CPU|^Phys"

CPU usage: 3.27% user, 14.75% sys, 81.96% idle 
PhysMem: 5807M used (1458M wired), 10G unused.
```

Or use `sysctl`

```
sysctl vm.loadavg
vm.loadavg: { 1.31 1.85 2.00 }
```

Or use `vm_stat`

```
vm_stat
Mach Virtual Memory Statistics: (page size of 4096 bytes)
Pages free:                                3569.
Pages active:                            832177.
Pages inactive:                          283212.
Pages speculative:                      2699727.
Pages throttled:                              0.
Pages wired down:                        372883.
```

Comment: I wanted to know which process is taking max cpu utilisation. When i tried top , i found output varying instantly and unable to capture output. Thank you and please help me to know it better

Comment: Thank you. please let me know how to interpret sysctl vm.loadavg output. And also as per my knowledge i think virtual memory is used when RAM gets exhausted. So this vm_stat is showing RAM or virtual memory. correct me if i am wrong please.

Comment: This is not really the place to give lengthy descriptions of parameters and how to debug memory/CPU problems - try having a Google around some of the command names and output field names... http://nonfunctionaltestingtools.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/vmstat-output-explained.html