# How to get CPU utilization in % in terminal (mac)

Tags: macos, terminal, cpu

Ive seen the same question asked on linux and windows but not mac (terminal). Can anyone tell me how to get the current processor utilization in %, so an example output would be `40%`. Thanks

Comment: This works on a Mac `ps -e -o %cpu | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

Comment: thanks this is what i wanted, just got to add the % now! thanks

Comment: @vcsjones, post this as an answer so OP could accept it

Comment: Why not launch Activity Monitor?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This works on a Mac (includes the %):

```
ps -A -o %cpu | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s "%"}'
```

To break this down a bit:

`ps` is the process status tool. Most *nix like operating systems support it. There are a few flags we want to pass to it:

- `-A` means all processes, not just the ones running as you.
- `-o` lets us specify the output we want. In this case, it all we want to the cpu% column of `ps`'s output.

This will get us a list of all of the processes cpu usage, like

```
0.0
1.3
27.0
0.0
```

We now need to add up this list to get a final number, so we pipe ps's output to `awk`. awk is a pretty powerful tool for parsing and operating on text. We just simply add up the numbers, then print out the result, and add a "%" on the end.

Comment: That method isn't very accurate since these values are rounded. The real CPU usage might be much bigger or much smaller, which can be checked with the Activity Monitor.

Comment: I am using this command to get the % CPU usage on Mac, but I am getting certain percentage values which are greater than 100. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: This is super helpful because it works in the recovery mode terminal. Thanks.
@Questionnaire You may see >100% because you have more than 1 core. Or because of rounding issues.

Comment: Also works over SSH, for checking on remote machines! @Questionnaire: chmac is right; you'll see the same thing if you sum up CPU utilization across processes in Activity Monitor; maximum utilization = (# cores * 100%).

Comment: This can't be a valid answer -- the measurement of CPU usage is *very* inaccurate compared to the approaches using `top -l` or what is reported from the macOS activity monitor.

Answer (score 8):

Building on previous answers from @Jon R. and @Rounak D, the following line prints the sum of user and system values, with the added percent.  I've have tested this value and I like that it roughly tracks well with the percentages shown in the [macOS Activity Monitor](https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac).

```sh
top -l  2 | grep -E "^CPU" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $3 + $5"%" }'
```

You can then capture that value in a variable in script like this:

```sh
cpu_percent=$(top -l  2 | grep -E "^CPU" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $3 + $5"%" }')
```

PS: You might also be interested in the output of uptime, which shows system load.

Answer (score 7):

Adding up all those CPU % can give a number > 100% (probably multiple cores).

Here's a simpler method, although it comes with some problems:

```
top -l 2 | grep -E "^CPU"
```

This gives 2 samples, the first of which is nonsense (because it calculates CPU load between samples).

Also, you need to use RegEx like `(\d+\.\d*)%` or some string functions to extract values, and add "user" and "sys" values to get the total.

(From [How to get CPU utilisation, RAM utilisation in MAC from commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168054/how-to-get-cpu-utilisation-ram-utilisation-in-mac-from-commandline))

Answer (score 4):

Building upon @Jon R's answer, we can pick up the user CPU utilization through some simple pattern matching

```sh
top -l 1 | grep -E "^CPU" | grep -Eo '[^[:space:]]+%' | head -1
```

And if you want to get rid of the last `%` symbol as well,

```sh
top -l 1 | grep -E "^CPU" | grep -Eo '[^[:space:]]+%' | head -1 | sed s/\%/\/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
printf "$(ps axo %cpu | awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { printf "%.1f\n", sum }' | tail -n 1),"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
top -F -R -o cpu
```

-F Do not calculate statistics on shared libraries, also known as frameworks.

-R Do not traverse and report the memory object map for each process.

-o cpu Order by CPU usage

[Answer Source](https://osxdaily.com/2009/10/06/monitoring-cpu-usage-on-your-mac-a-better-top-command/)

Answer (score 0):

This only produces statistics, and skips extra work:

```
top -R -F -n 0
```

To find CPU utlliization, parse this as shown by [Michael Behrens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11972755/michael-behrens):

```
top -R -F -n 0 -l 2 -s 0 | grep -E "^CPU" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $3 + $5"%" }'
```

Extra `-s 0` makes the second print follow with no delay (the default is 1 sec). [Jon R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12508260/jon-r) has explained very well why one sample is not enough: it shows average CPU usage for an unspecified period of time.