# Get total CPU usage from the terminal on a Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to get the total CPU usage from the terminal on a Mac. I want the output to be as simple as `40.5%`.

I was looking at this question [How to get CPU utilization in % in terminal (mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855440/how-to-get-cpu-utilization-in-in-terminal-mac) but there seems to be problems with the top answer because sometimes the value goes above 100%.

It also looks like running this command makes the CPU spike which isn't giving an accurate value.

Is there a better way to do this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `top` would display the CPU usage, but the total CPU utilization is a transient value. It varies wildly. But in any case `top` would work.Look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html) for more. I'm not quite sure on how to parse top's output to get the exact number you want

Comment: Your Mac has more than one CPU, so a multithreaded process can use more than 100% of a CPU.